# Rails pass user email to forgot password form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I used devise to integrate user registration and login. Now I also have forgot password page.

What would be the best way to pass user's email from the user_email textfield on the login form to the forgot password form, so the user doesn't need to put in his/her email twice?

Link to forgot password page:

```
<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

Sign in form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :required => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :required => true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Forgot password form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `resource` already has details of the `current_user`

Comment: Thank you. It return #<User:0x007f512c91ee78>. How could I extract passed email from that?

Comment: Are you using jQuery already?

Comment: I am using jQuery in my application, but not for this task

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
 <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, object: resource %></div>
```

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately it does nothing. But if I set value: resource I get this in the form: #<User:0x007f512c91ee78>

Comment: It returns an empty field

Comment: if you mean give value to the email_field like this: value: "john", then yes, it is working

Comment: then try value: resource.email

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work. Returns an empty field

Comment: yes. We can't do here, because its a new method. but you can achieve this by another way. use session to save a user_id and use it here.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the value of that textfield as a parameter with link_to?

Comment: better way use session. that will be more effective.

Comment: Could you show me and example on how to use session for that? I am having some trouble implementing this.